# why increasing the pointer value by one doesn't allow to set a value at that location?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>;
void main(){
  int x=10;
  int *y=&x+1;
  *y=15;
  printf("\n Address of x is %u",&x);
  printf("\n Value of y is %d",*y);
}
```

In this code why is value of `*y` not 15, 
in output the value of x=25908 and value of y=25912 ?
I want to know why 15 is not shown as output when i made the value at the next address to x as 15 ?

Comment: Note: `void main()`--> `int main(void)`

Comment: _next address?_ Who gave you the _right_ to use the _next_ address?

Comment: It is likely that the "next address" is `y` itself. So when you assign `15` to that address you are changing `y` so that it points to another location.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question actually for a beginner. He wrote 15 to `*y` and then printed `*y` out and didn't get 15

Comment: What compiler are you using? I tried this with gcc and it immediately segmention faults (as I guessed it would).

Comment: @KlasLindbäck - I thought the same thing as well, but it's not true on gcc. `y` comes before `x` in memory order (in the stack frame).

Comment: @MarkLakata When I run the code using gcc in Linux I get a seg fault, so I'm not convinced he is using gcc.

Answer (score 5):

In your code, by writing

```
 int *y=&x+1;
```

you're accessing memory which is not allocated to your process (program). It invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In case, `x` would have been an array name, and having sufficient memory allocated for the *offset* (here, the value `1`), dereferencing obtained `y` from this operation would have been legal. But, here, `x` being a single variable, you cannot expect to access the so-called *next* address, it is invalid.

That said, to print an address, always use the form

```
printf("Address is %p\n", (void *)&var);
```

or similar.

Comment: If `x` had been an array, `int *y = &x + 1` wouldn't even compile. Were you thinking of `x + 1`?

Comment: if we don't use (void *) then also it would display the correct value. What is the significance of using (void *) ?

Comment: it display the correct value because of pure lucks. In other systems/platforms/compilers... it may give you a segfault or [nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)

Answer (score 4):

Because the thing that you are doing has **undefined behavior**. You are writing to an unknown address (address of `x` + `sizeof(int)` bytes) and you have no idea what the compilers puts in that address and how it arranges the order of the local variables.

Maybe the parameters that are pushed on the stack on `printf` call have overriden 15 and maybe anything else has happened.

Note that compiling the same code with different flags and optimization level may cause different result. In other words **undefined behavior**.

Comment: if there any other way of doing what i want to do. I want to put a datatype of my choice to the pointer next to x i.e in memory location &x+1, and i don't want to use a array ?

Comment: There's no way for you. The compiler does not have to put the next variable in the source code to the next address in memory or even in the same memory space. It may not store the variable in memory at all if it notices that the registers are enough. Only pointer arithmetics applied to the same array are guaranteed to have defined behavior

Comment: @AmanBisht `array` guarantees you continues memory of the same data type. Nothing else, even struct, can guarantee that `&varA+1` will point to the next well defind memory area.

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
x= 10;
```

you have memory allocated to store the value 10 and the memory location is `&x` so this is the memory which can be accessed by you, accessing unowned memory leads to undefined behavior in this case you are accessing `&x + 1` which is not under your control